# Reading only the latest replied content using java mail multipart MIME

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I wanted to read a multipart MIME mail only the latest replied content (excluding the original email content) using java mail. Is there any API support available other that doing string parsing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no standard for how original messages are included in a reply message, although there's some common conventions.   You're pretty much stuck with doing string processing to try to figure out what convention any message is using.

Answer (score 1):

I did this way as I cannot find out any api for this.

```
if (messageContent.indexOf("From")!=-1)
                    {
                        messageContent = messageContent.substring(0, messageContent.indexOf("From")).trim();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        messageContent = messageContent.trim();
                    }
```

Please correct me if I am doing wrong.

Comment: This fails when the content itself has a word "From",  is there any other way ?